# Identify/change a field with formula within MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document, which contains some fields in the header and some in the text.
The field in the header can be changed by:

```
Dim oHF As HeaderFooter
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    Do Until i > ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
        Set oHF = ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
        For Each fieldLoop In oHF.Range.Fields
            If fieldLoop.Code.Text = " NUMPAGES \* MERGEFORMAT \* CHARFORMAT " Then
                fieldLoop.Code.Text = " SECTIONPAGES \* MERGEFORMAT \* CHARFORMAT "
            End If
        Next fieldLoop
        Set oHF = ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
        For Each fieldLoop In oHF.Range.Fields
            If fieldLoop.Code.Text = " NUMPAGES \* MERGEFORMAT \* CHARFORMAT " Then
                fieldLoop.Code.Text = " SECTIONPAGES \* MERGEFORMAT \* CHARFORMAT "
            End If
        Next fieldLoop
        i = i + 1
    Loop
```

But if I try to change the fields in the "main" document via:

```
Dim fieldX As field
    For Each fieldX In ActiveDocument.Fields
        If CStr(fieldX.Code) Like "*NUMPAGES*" Then
            fieldx.Code.Text = " SECTIONPAGES \* MERGEFORMAT \* CHARFORMAT "
        End If
    Next fieldX
```

it doens not work.
Even ActiveDocument.fields.count gives me a "0".
But there is definive one field containing a formula in the text...
How can I address this field to change its value?
best regards,
Andreas

Comment: You need to determine where in the document the mysterious field is. I would first try displaying the field codes (Alt+F9). Hopefully then you will then be able to identify just where the field is. `ActiveDocument.Fields.Count` won't include fields in headers or footers.

Comment: If the For Each does not find a field, it's probably because the field is inside a *floating* obbect such as a textbox or other shape.